# Java Swing WebBrowser How to notice that an URL does not excist?

Tags: java, swing, browser, io, jeditorpane

I couldn't find the solution for my question on stackoverflow. Could be that I'm just bad at looking, if so I do apologize.

---

Anyhow on to the **question**:
I have made my own browser, and I want it to give the user an error if an URL does not excist or not responding. I use the following command from Java Swing:
EditorPane = setPage(url)    // where EditorPane is a JEditorPane

---

SetPage(URL url) Only gives me an error if it's not an url sent in the parameter. So how can i get feedback if the URL is not responding?

---

Thank you in advance, - Julian
ps: the comments are in swedish but they are not very helpful!

```
    private void loadPage(URL url, boolean AddOrNot) {
    try{
        System.out.println("loadPage Try");
        displayEditorPane.setPage(url);           // setter sidan till url

        //URL newUrl = displayEditorPane.getPage(); //ger den nuvarande sidans url funkar ei
        //displayEditorPane.setPage(newUrl); //get error ?!?
        String hist=url.toString();
        textField.setText(hist); // men denna fungerar

        if(AddOrNot){//lägger till url i history-list om du inte använt back / forward knapp
            history.add(hist);
            JMenuItem historyFile = new JMenuItem(hist);
            historyFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                   textField.setText(hist);
                   position=0;
                   Launch(true);
               } 
            });
            HistoryMenu.add(historyFile);
        }
        //** kollar om forward och back knapparna ska vara aktiva **//
        if(position!=history.size()-1){
            BackButton.setEnabled(true);
        }else{
            BackButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
        if(position>0){
            ForwardButton.setEnabled(true);
        }else{
            ForwardButton.setEnabled(false);
        }


    }catch(IOException io ){
        System.out.println("loadPage Catch " + io);
        msgError("Unable to open page");
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I have made my own browser, .. is a JEditorPane"*  The `JEditorPane` component was never intended as a web browser.  It only supports a sub-set of HTML 3.2 elements, limited styles, no javascript support..  If this is a serious project, I'd recommend moving to Java-FX and using the [`WebView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) component.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your concern but it's far from a serious project. It's a school task, for introduction Java, so they wanted us to dip our toes in the water and make a browser that only supports HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
displayEditorPane.setPage(url);
```

If you need more advanced feedback of loading and success, it will be necessary to abandon this simple approach for a more complicated one where the app. takes control of reading the content.  For that, look to `URLConnection` & `HttpURLConnection`.  Methods in particular:

- [`URLConnection.getInputStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getInputStream--):

  > Returns an input stream that reads from this open connection. A `SocketTimeoutException` can be thrown when reading from the returned input stream if the read timeout expires before data is available for read.
- [`HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getResponseCode--):

  > Gets the status code from an HTTP response message. For example, in the case of the following status lines:

  ```
  HTTP/1.0 200 OK
  HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
  ```

  > It will return `200` and `401` respectively. Returns `-1` if no code can be discerned from the response (i.e., the response is not valid HTTP).

---

For information on dealing with streams, see the [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html) lesson of the tutorial.